# Pythonic Way to Change Series Values for Index Elements in Series and a Separate Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series:

```
    s

A   1
B   0
C   1
D  -1
E  -1
F   0
...
```

and a dataframe with a subset of the series index values:

```
df

    one   two  three ....
A    
C   
D  
F   
...
```

the contents of the df are not relevant in my question.

I am looking for the most Pythonic way to check the series index against the dataframe index and if the index element is in both series and dataframe indices, change the series value to zero.

The result I'm looking for is for the series to look like this based on sample s and df provided above:

```
    s

A   0
B   0
C   0
D   0
E  -1
F   0
```

Note that some series values were 0 to begin with and they stay 0.  The ones where the index elements are in both are changed to 0 in the series.

I can iterate through the index but looking for more pythonic way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
s[s.index.isin(df.index)] = 0
```

Yields:

```
A    0
B    0
C    0
D    0
E   -1
F    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Could use update, with a dummy column of all `0`. Should be fast.

```
import pandas as pd

s.update(pd.Series(0, index=df.index))
```